# Preserve pull requests when moving repository between Azure DevOps projects

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

I have two Azure DevOps projects within the same account, and I'd like to move a repository from one to the other. The page [Explore how to move git repositories between Team Projects with full-fidelity history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/articles/move-git-repos-between-team-projects?view=vsts) gives a great explanation of how to move the repository while preserving the full history of all branches. However, all information about pull requests (the comments in them, who approved, etc.) is lost.

> Is there any way to preserve pull request info when moving a repo from one Azure DevOps project to another (*within the same account*)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there's no way. Pull requests are scoped to the team project in which they were created and cannot be moved.

Comment: That's good to know (but sad news). Is this specified anywhere in the official Azure DevOps documentation?

Comment: No. In general, assume that if it's in a team project, it's scoped to that project and cannot be moved unless stated *otherwise*.

Comment: is there a way when we migrate repo to another server we can push PR's too??

Comment: @user6936970 That's the question that I answered back in 2018. The answer is still the same: No.