# Move a GIT repo incl. pull requests to a different project

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to move a GIT repo to a different project without losing the pull request (and other) data that is related to the GIT repo and is stored in the project context.

Is that possible in Azure DevOps?

Thank you

Comment: Is the statement from this post still true? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673323/preserve-pull-requests-when-moving-repository-between-azure-devops-projects?rq=1

Comment: Yes, it's still true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move repos from one Team Project to another you can check: [Explore how to move git repositories between Team Projects with full-fidelity history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/move-git-repos-between-team-projects?view=azure-devops)

And till now preserving PR is not supported when moving repos. Other data like commits/pushes can be stored well but not PR. You may check the commits graph(Commits Tab) to get some info about the PR:

[image]

But you can't find anything in Pull request Tab, cause this info is not stored during the migration.

Besides, consider posting a feature request in [User Voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) if you do want the feature come true. The product team would review and consider it then. Hope my answer helps :)